# Does this example for indeterminacy in classical dynamics translate to real life？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, causality

I read the paper *[Example of indeterminacy in classical dynamics](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Edsbaero/library/BhatIndeterminacy.pdf).*
I understand the paper: Because the differential equation does not satisfy the Lipschitz condition, its solution is not unique, and thus there is indeterminacy.

But is it really possible in physics, as in the example described in the paper, for the ball to rest at the origin to suddenly deviate to the left or right from the origin, which violates the law of causality? Or does the physical world not follow the law of causality?

Comment: It is not causality that is at fault, it is the fact that that in the physical world the Lipschitz condition is satisfied.

Comment: @user619894: *in the physical world the Lipschitz condition is satisfied* – How could you possibly know?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Personal experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can’t possibly know.

We know that classical mechanics completely breaks down on atomic scales (in fact, classical mechanics can be considered just a simplifying limit case of quantum mechanics). However, if we impose a lower scale limit that we can reasonably consider, every surface fulfils the Lipschitz condition.

On top, any experiment testing this would require us to create a perfectly round ball and perfectly place it on a perfectly crafted surface in a perfect vacuum. This is clearly impossible in our world due to quantum effects, the atomic nature of matter, etc. (Of course, you can consider an analogous experiment that doesn’t require a ball and such, but you would run into similar issues.) We can’t say how things would be in a hypothetical universe that is classical all the way down – because we are not living in that universe.

Comment: thanks a lot, I got the answer from your last sentence, just like there is no real infinity and infinitesimal in real life, such as the scale of the universe is very large, but it has not been proved that it is a flat Euclidean geometric space, there is a conjecture that in fact the universe is similar to spherical geometry, not infinite, and maybe there is no infinitesimal too, just like the energy quantum found at present. So we cannot know what "common sense" is in an infinite world unless we define "common sense".